# Удалить те элементы массива, которые встречаются в нем ровно два раза

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо удалить из списка повторяющиеся элементы.
К примеру:

```
data = ["Homer", "Bart", "Lisa", "Marge", "Lisa"]
```

Необходимо удалить из списка повторяющийся элемент, в данном случае "Lisa"

Как это сделать?

Comment: `set(data)` -> {'Bart', 'Homer', 'Marge', 'Lisa'}

Comment: А те, что трижды встречаются ?

Comment: MBo, в описании вказано что ровно значить не больше 2 и не меньше

Comment: @GGO Ну это должно наводить на мысль, что элементы нужно посчитать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

data = ['Homer', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Marge', 'Lisa']
frequencies = Counter(data)
filtered = [i for i in data if frequencies.get(i) != 2]
```